# NSTextAlignment can not be represented in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridge

In my Swift class, I exposed an variable to objective c by defining it as

```
@objc var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment? {
    didSet {
        if textAlignment != nil {
            label.textAlignment = textAlignment!
        }
    }
}
```

And it is **Wrong**! because compiler complains that it is not a type that can be represented in Objective-C.

[image]

---

But the followings are right

```
var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment? {
    didSet {
        label.textAlignment = textAlignment!
    }
}
```

Or

```
@objc var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment {
    didSet {
        label.textAlignment = textAlignment
    }
}
```

So it looks like if I expose the method to objective-C, It can not be optional value. However if I use it internally, I can! Is it because it is a scalar value where in Objective-C we have no way to represent it as nil?

My intention was just want to make it not compulsory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTextAlignment` is an enum, not an class - the `textAlignment` variable can't be mapped as optional to objective c because that would require it to be a pointer to an object type.

Try:

```
@objc var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment { 
  ...
}
```

Or, if you really need it to be optional, you could expose it to Objective C as an `NSNumber`, wrapping the `textAlignment.rawValue` or setting to nil when no value is needed.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. It is just a scalar value in objective c. My intention was just want to make it not compulsory.